# Background 'Watermark' type image for UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, background

I'm trying to set an image as the background for a uiview, here's how I do it:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermark.png"];
self.view.layer.contents = bgImage.CGImage;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This works in iOS5, but on iOS4 all I get is a black background. Any ideas?

I tried other approaches such as colorWithPatternImage, but that doesn't get the image displayed properly.

Comment: This should work since, I believe, iPhone OS 2.0. Make sure the view has a non-zero size and the image is not nil due to other unrelated circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the second line to this:

```
self.view.layer.contents = (id)bgImage.CGImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
[backgroundImage release];
```

In this case you can manage the view hierachy and put the `UIImageView` under the current view. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is nice and OK, just use this for your cell `cellForAtIndexpath`

```
 UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermark.png"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
 [cell.contentView addSubview: imageView];
```